# Laravel VUEJS axios how to insert array to database

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have an array which is passed from vue to controller:

```
axios.post('./api/po',{addStudent:this.addStudentForm});
```

This is what my controller looks like:

```
return $request->addStudent;
```

I was successful in passing it through the controller as it was able to return it:

```
{student: "test", year: 1, age: "13"}
```

How do I insert it to the database? I've tried doing something like this in the controller:

```
return Students::create([
       'student': $request['student'],
       'year': $request['year'],
       'age': $request['age'],
]);
```

However it does not work and returns an error.

```
Error:

    Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'student' cannot be null
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which error does it return? We can not help you if you don't provide all informations about your project.

Comment: edited it with the error. Sorry about that

Comment: No worries. Check my answer I found the problem without the error.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use

```
$request->student;
```

student/year/age is a part of your `$request` body and laravel can access it like that.

Just an important note that `$request` is coming from the 
`Illuminate\Http\Request;`

So make sure to `use` it in your file and inject it in your function like:

```
 public function createRecord(Request $request){

    return Students::create([
           'student'=> $request->student,
           'year'=> $request->year,
           'age'=> $request->age,
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you're able to return `$request->addStudent` and you get the desired response: `{student: "test", year: 1, age: "13"}`. This means you need to access the request properties like this:

```php
return Students::create([
       'student': $request->addStudent['student'],
       'year': $request->addStudent['year'],
       'age': $request->addStudent['age'],
]);
```

Alternatively, you could configure your axios request to send the `addStudent` object as the request body like this:

```js
axios.post('./api/po', this.addStudentForm);
```

Then you'll be able to access the properties individually right off the request:

```php
return Students::create([
       'student': $request->student,
       'year': $request->year,
       'age': $request->age,
]);
```